# How can I setup dreamhost shared host with jenkins cd

Tags: jenkins, ssh, continuous-integration, cd, dreamhost

I want to ssh to the host and pull my git changes through Jenkins. But I cannot find how to do it with user and password. sshpass doesnt work either.